# Why is the Ubuntu VM screen corrupted on my HiDpi laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, dell-xps, display-settings

When running a clean install of Ubuntu 17.04 on a fresh Dell XPS 9360 (3200x1800 display) I was soon shown the following screen after the initial boot:
[image: corrupted screen]

Basically, the displayed image is corrupt and incomprehensible. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the allotted default amount of VRAM (video ram) in Virtualbox is not sufficient for the high-resolution display. Simply try increasing it. By increasing it from the default (19MB?) to 128MB the problem went away.

[image: Video memory]

This might also be related to the Unity desktop environment, which according to the specs requires a video card of at least 256 MB, a requirement most integrated solutions will fail. In that case, try another desktop environment, such as XFCE (XUbuntu) which does not have a 3D rendered desktop by default.

Comment: I had mine at 64MB for Ubuntu Mate, which worked fine in 17.10, but needed 128MB for 18.04.

Answer (score 5):

On my macOS host, increasing the amount of processors allocated to the VM from 1 -> 4 fixed this issue for me. My guest was Lubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It worked for me too.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me, even though VirtualBox complains with "invalid settings detected" (since the host only has 2 CPUs).

Answer (score 0):

While trying to install an old version of ubuntu (10.04) on my Ubuntu 19.04 (beta) on Lenovo X1 carbon - I had this issue.

I changed the "Graphics Controller" in machine settings to VBOXVGA and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you add a little context about your system so readers can assess how this might apply to them?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, done...